# How do I loop through this nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

How can I loop through the array below with PHP in order to to display the list? There may be more than 7 items in the list. Should I use `foreach`, `while`?

My desired output is:

```
APPLE
PEAR
BANANA
etc
```

Here is the array structure:

```
Array  
(  
    [main_category] => Array  
        (  
            [0] => APPLES  
            [1] => PEARS  
            [2] => BANANAS  
            [3] => PEACHES  
            [4] => ORANGES  
            [5] => KIWIS  
            [6] => PASSION FRUITS  
        )      
)
```

Comment: You can use while, for, foreach, etc as with any other data set. If you paste some of the code you've tried we could pitch in on why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you only want the data from `main_category`:

```
foreach($array['main_category'] as $value){ 
    //do whatever you want with the  value
    echo $value;
}
```

Expected output:

```
PEARS BANANAS PEACHES ORANGES KIWIS PASSION FRUITS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($your_array as $vals){
   foreach($vals['main_category'] as $val){
      echo $val;
      echo "<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it would be enough for the OP to do: foreach($array['main_category'] as $value){

Comment: @JimL : YES..If he wants only the data from `'main_category'`